# how I can called my form

Tags: odoo

I created a form view, with the goal that when I click the new button, it will go to the form that I created. But why do I always see an error?

```
**ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: integer = boolean
LINE 1: select name, model from ir_ui_view where (id=false or inheri...
                                                    ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.**
```

That's the picture, thank you.

(If you want to see a picture, please tell me your email, because I cannot put the picture here. Thanks.)

Answer (score 1):

After Seeing your traceback it looks like that you are passing the value of `view_id = False`.
It should be "ID" of the form view you want to open.

Comment: sorry..I little confused. here is my new code                 <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="passenger_list_action">
   <field name="name">Passenger</field>
   <field name="res_model">travel.management.ticket</field>
   <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
   <field name="view_type">tree</field>
    <field name="id" ref="management_ticket_tree_view"/>
  </record>         still error. did you mean like that ?

Comment: view_id = self.pool.get('ir.ui.view').search(cr,uid,[('model','=','your_model_name'),
                            ('name','=','your_view_name')])
        
return {
            'view_type': 'form',
            "view_mode": 'form',
            'res_model': 'your_model',
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'target': 'new',
            'view_id': view_id,
            'context': context
        }